# Join a VM to an existing domain using template

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I am using arm template to build multiple vm and join them to an existing domain.However, it fails with following error.
[image]

The resource the template complaining about do exists.

The template to join is as shown below.

```
{

      "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
      "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
      "name": "[toLower(concat(variables('varnodeNamePrefix'),copyIndex(1),'.',variables('varlocation'),'.cloudapp.azure.com','/joindomain'))]",
      "location": "[variables('varlocation')]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines', concat(variables('varnodeNamePrefix'),copyIndex(1)))]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', concat(variables('varstorageName'),copyIndex(1)))]"
      ],


      "properties": {
        "publisher": "Microsoft.Compute",
        "type": "JsonADDomainExtension",
        "typeHandlerVersion": "1.3",
        "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
        "settings": {
          "Name": "[variables('vardomainToJoin')]",
          "OUPath": "[variables('varouPath')]",
          "User": "[variables('vardomainUsername')]",
          "Restart": "true",
          "Options": "[variables('vardomainJoinOptions')]"
        },
        "protectedSettings": {
          "Password": "[variables('vardomainPassword')]"
        }
      },
      "copy": {
        "name": "dominjoin",
        "count": "[variables('varvmCount')]"
      }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: hard to tell whats wrong exactly, but does the vm get provisioned succesfully?

Comment: Yes. No errors with vm provisioning. I can remote on to it. If I try to add the vm to the domain locally from the vm, it asks for the user name and password.

Comment: can you share the vm resource from the template as well?

Comment: Please see the full template
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1kxMV9AO_YFtbsAteaYipA7rJKfmqwlnP

The domain is in a different resource group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your extension name should be this: `vm_name/extension_name`, so in your case it should be:

```
"name": "[toLower(concat(variables('varnodeNamePrefix'),copyIndex(1),'/joindomain'))]",
```

this is valid for all the subresources in azure. to identify "to which" vm this extension belongs, it needs the vm resource name, not the fqdn or ip address or something like that (because its an Azure level operation).

Comment: Good news and bad news.. Good news is, the template is not failing with previous error. Bad news is "The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'" code:VMExtensionProvisioningError

Comment: well, thats a completely different error, i suggest you raise a new question ;)